# Why not measure the velocity of a quantum particle by $\frac{\Delta \vec{x}}{\Delta t}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, foundations

Why is it not possible in quantum mechanics to measure the velocity (and thus momentum) of a particle just by two position and time measurements and get it approximately by

$$
\vec{v} = \frac{\vec{x}_2 - \vec{x}_1}{t_2 - t_1}
$$

just like in classical mechanics. I found a quote from Niels Bohr (from the [Como Lecture](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/bohr/quantum_postulate.html)) about this, but I don't understand why this statement excludes determing the velocity and momentum in the simple way described above:

> This is particularly to be remembered when comparing the results of
>   successive observations. Indeed, the position of an individual at two
>   given moments can be measured with any desired degree of accuracy; but
>   if, from such measurements, we would calculate the velocity of the
>   individual in the ordinary way, it must be clearly realised that we
>   are dealing with an abstraction, from which no unambiguous information
>   concerning the previous or future behaviour of the individual can be
>   obtained.

Comment: Are you aware of and familiar with the uncertainty principle?

Comment: Measurement in quantum mechanics generally changes the state of the system. So your first measurement (that of $\vec x_1$) changes the state of the particle and the second position $\vec x_2$ is then measured on a *different* state. Your formula for $\vec v$ therefore makes little sense even as a definition of what velocity of a particle in quantum mechanics might be.

Comment: Ontologically this is perfectly possible but the results do not form a physically useful set of measurements _in general_. In special cases like in high energy physics, we are treating "particles" (which is a misnomer, it's really field quanta) as perfectly classical. Particle detectors at LHC (like ATLAS and CMS) consist of layers of pixelated detection elements with known coordinates. The data analysis does, indeed, assume that particles are moving with near constant velocity from pixel to pixel. This is possible because the uncertainty relation is never violated.

Comment: I don't know about Bohr's quote, but this is covered in Landau & Lifshitz, and it's very simple: because measuring the position collapses the state to one with no definite velocity, your expression doesn't have a limit as $t_2 \to t_1$.

Comment: You can compute these quantities just fine, but the result will be meaningless, because the particle doesn't have a definite velocity to begin with.

Comment: @Asher: Yes I am familiar with the UP.  But how does this answer my question?

Comment: @TomášBrauner But if it was in a position eigenstate it should  work?

Comment: @Javier I don't want to take the limit $t_2 \to t_1$, sure this would be even better, but the question is just about the average velocity of a small intervall. Do you have a reference to Landau (which page?)

Comment: @Julia You would still have a problem since the eigenstate of the coordinate operator is not normalizable. (The same applies to any initial state since *after* the first coordinate measurement, the system will be in a position eigenstate.) Moreover, as Javier pointed out, such a state has no definite velocity, so this is not even a very interesting special case.

Comment: @TomášBrauner Isn't "not normalizable" just a problem of the formalism? Just use a rigged hilbert space...